# How to do prediction using a saved model which is trained with Estimator and Dataset API?

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, deep-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I have trained a cnn model using `tf.estimator` and `tf.data.TFRecordDataset`, which define a model in `model_fn` funcition and input in `input_fn` function. Also using an [one-shot iterator](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/datasets#creating_an_iterator) to get one batch examples at a time.

Now I have trained model files(ckpt, meta, index) in a directory. What I want to do is predicting a image's label based on the trained model without training and evaluation again. The image can be numpy array but not possible a TFRecords file(which used when traing).

I can't find an effictive solution after trying all day. I only can get the value of weights and biases and don't know how to make my predicting image and model compatible.

FYI, my training code is [here](https://github.com/secsilm/understaing-datasets-estimators-tfrecords/blob/master/cifar10-estimator-dataset.py).

The similar question is [Prediction from model saved with `tf.estimator.Estimator` in Tensorflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43966073/prediction-from-model-saved-with-tf-estimator-estimator-in-tensorflow)
, but no accepted answer and my model input is using the dataset api.

So reaaally need help. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I have answered a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48120679/5098368).

To make predictions using a custom input, you need to use the built-in [`predict`](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/estimator/Estimator#predict) method of Estimators:

```py
estimator = tf.estimator.Estimator(model_fn, ...)

predict_input_fn = ...  # define this using tf.data

predict_results = estimator.predict(predict_input_fn)
for idx, prediction in enumerate(predict_results):
    print(idx)
    for key in prediction:
        print("...{}: {}".format(key, prediction[key]))
```