# Tensorflow: Predicting data labels from trained dense layer

Tags: tensorflow, machine-learning, neural-network, layer

I have trained a simple feed forward neural network using tf.layers.dense
However, after training the layers using the optimise and train, I do not know how to use the trained layers to predict the labels for new data that I would like to evaluate.I have searched stackoverflow and google on how to do this and the closest answer I found was [Using a created tensorflow model for predicting](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48071820/using-a-created-tensorflow-model-for-predicting)
However, is there not an easier way to use a trained layer other than saving that layer and calling it up again?

This neural network is trained to predict the output concentration from a chemical reaction. The chemical reaction output can be modelled with a coupled ODE and be solved easily, but I am trying to use neural networks to give an approximate solution.

```
#Making Data
training_features=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random_sample([500,3]),columns=['ca','t','T'])
training_labels=conc_out(training_features,trans)
validation_features=pd.DataFrame(data=np.random.random_sample([30,3]),columns=['ca','t','T'])
validation_labels=conc_out(training_features,trans)

def my_input_fn(features, targets, batch_size=1,num_epochs=None,shuffle=True):
    #Creating Dataset importing function, returning get_next from iterator
    #features=features.to_dict('list')

    ds=tf.data.Dataset.from_tensor_slices((features,targets))
    if shuffle:
        ds=ds.shuffle(buffer_size=10000)

    ds=ds.batch(batch_size).repeat(num_epochs)

    features,labels=ds.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()
    return features,labels

def nn(input_featurs,hidden_layers=[10]):
    net=tf.layers.dense(input_featurs,hidden_layers[0],activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    if len(hidden_layers)>1:
        for i in range(len(hidden_layers)-1):
            net=tf.layers.dense(net,hidden_layers[i+1],activation=tf.nn.sigmoid)
    logits=tf.layers.dense(net,2,activation=None)
    return logits

def train_nn_regression_model(
        learning_rate,
        epochs,
        batch_size,
        hidden_units,
        training_examples,
        training_targets,
        validation_examples,
        validation_targets):

    # Create input functions.

    features,labels=my_input_fn(training_examples,training_targets,batch_size=batch_size)
    predictions=nn(features,hidden_units)
    loss=tf.reduce_mean(tf.nn.sigmoid_cross_entropy_with_logits(logits=predictions,labels=labels))
    train_op=tf.train.AdamOptimizer(learning_rate=learning_rate).minimize(loss)

    with tf.Session() as sess:
        #Training neural network
        sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())
        training_predictions_before = pd.DataFrame(data=sess.run(training_predictions), columns=['TP_Ca', 'TP_Cb'])
        print(training_predictions_before.head(10))
        for epoch in range(epochs):
            epoch_loss=0
            for _ in range(int(training_examples.shape[0]/batch_size)):
                _,loss_value=sess.run([train_op,loss])
                epoch_loss+=loss_value
            print('Epoch : ',epoch+1, ' out of ', epochs,' . Epoch loss = ',epoch_loss)


        training_predictions=pd.DataFrame(data=sess.run(training_predictions),columns=['TP_Ca','TP_Cb'])
        print(training_predictions.head(10))

train_nn_regression_model(
        learning_rate=0.002,
        epochs=10,
        batch_size=20,
        hidden_units=[100],
        training_examples=training_features,
        training_targets=training_labels,
        validation_examples=validation_features,
        validation_targets=validation_labels)
```

When I run the code, training_predictions_before and training_predictions gives the exact same answer. However, should'nt training_predictions give a different answer as it is executed after the training operations?

Thank you!

Edit: I have edited the code to ensure that everything runs within the same session.

Comment: When you call `training_predictions=nn(features,hidden_units)` a new network with uninitialized variables is being created.

Comment: Oh thanks rvinas! I tried to reinitialise all global variables then ran training_predictions=nn(features,hidden_units)
However, my predictions I got was very poor and is it because each time you reinitialise all the layers again, the trained weight and biases are 'reset' to random values, resulting in the neural network giving bad results?

Comment: This is because you have 2 different networks. You should only define one.

Comment: What do you mean by this?
If I only have one network, how do I input new features to that network to make predictions?
Do you mind showing an example of the correct code?
Thank you!